# Color Gradient on datapoints based on rows in gnuplot

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

I Have a dataset with a whole bunch of rows corresponding to points (x,y) on the plane. I want to plot this collection of points with a gradient so the first point in the list is blue, and as it plots more and more points from the list it shifts to red.

Is there any way to do this in gnuplot? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `linecolor palette z` option to do this. For example, if you have a datafile `test.dat` that looks like

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
```

then you can do

```
unset key
set palette defined ( 0 "blue", 1 "red" )
plot "test.dat" u 1:2:0 w p pt 7 ps 3 lc palette z
```

[image]